# Initialize List<Clothes> clothesList ; java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have 3 wardrobes , in each of them I added some clothes

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wardrobe wardrobe = new Wardrobe("LivingRoom", TypeCloset.LivingRoom);
        wardrobe.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.blouse, 95, "Patagonia"));
        wardrobe.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.vest, 15, "Zara"));
        wardrobe.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.pants, 125, "Adidas"));
        wardrobe.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.t_shirt, 55, "Nike"));

        Wardrobe wardrobe1 = new Wardrobe("BedRoom", TypeCloset.BedRoom);
        wardrobe1.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.shoes, 120, "Nike"));
        wardrobe1.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.blouse, 19, "Nina"));
        wardrobe1.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.vest, 5, "China"));
        wardrobe1.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.t_shirt, 10, "Legend"));
        wardrobe1.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.blouse, 80, "Patagonia"));

        Wardrobe wardrobe2 = new Wardrobe("Outdoor", TypeCloset.Outdoor);
        wardrobe2.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.t_shirt, 250, "Verse"));
        wardrobe2.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.pants, 700, "Louis"));
        wardrobe2.add(new Clothes(TypeClothes.blouse, 360, "Balancing"));

 List<Clothes> clothesList = new ArrayList<>(); // is an empty array lsit
        List<Wardrobe> wardrobeList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(wardrobe, wardrobe1, wardrobe2));

    Map<TypeClothes, Long> numberClothesPerType = getNumberClothesPerTypeClothes(clothesList);
    System.out.println("Number Clothes per Type: " + numberClothesPerType);

}
```

So I want to get  quantity per typeClothes  like this

```
public static Map<TypeClothes, Long> getNumberClothesPerTypeClothes(List<Clothes> clothesList) {
    return clothesList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Clothes::getTypeClothes, Collectors.counting()));
}
```

My output is correct :

```
Number Clothes per Type: {blouse=4, pants=2, shoes=1, t_shirt=3, vest=2}
```

But since I do not want to make my  clothesList looking like this but rather like I have done it above:

```
        Clothes clothes = new Clothes(TypeClothes.blouse, 95, "Patagonia");
        Clothes clothes1 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.vest, 15, "Zara");
        Clothes clothes2 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.pants, 125, "Adidas");
        Clothes clothes3 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.t_shirt, 55, "Nike");
        Clothes clothes4 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.blouse, 19, "Nina");
        Clothes clothes5 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.vest, 5, "China");
        Clothes clothes6 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.t_shirt, 10, "Legend");
        Clothes clothes7 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.blouse, 80, "Patagonia");
        Clothes clothes8 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.t_shirt, 250, "Verse");
        Clothes clothes9 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.pants, 700, "Louis");
        Clothes clothes10 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.blouse, 360, "Balancing");
        Clothes clothes11 = new Clothes(TypeClothes.shoes, 120, "Nike");

List<Clothes> clothesList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(clothes, clothes1, clothes2, clothes3, clothes4, clothes5, clothes6, clothes7, clothes8, clothes9, clothes10, clothes11));
```

How should I do it to get the list of clothes from the ones I added to the wardrobe but not having to create clothes and then add, so just from the ones I added?

Adding wardrobe class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Wardrobe {

    List<Clothes> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;
    private TypeCloset typeCloset;

    public Wardrobe(String name, TypeCloset typeCloset) {
        this.name = name;
        this.typeCloset = typeCloset;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public TypeCloset getType() {
        return typeCloset;
    }

    public void setType(TypeCloset typeCloset) {
        this.typeCloset = typeCloset;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Wardrobe{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", typeCloset=" + typeCloset +
                '}';
    }

    public void add(Clothes newClothes) {
        clothes.add(newClothes);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.clothes.size();
    }

    public Integer getPricePerCloset() {
        return this.clothes.stream()
                .mapToInt(Clothes::getPrice)
                .sum();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have implemented a get method in your Wardrobe (which you should provide the definition) like:

`public list<Clothes> getClothes()`

From the list of wardrobes, you can do

`wardrobesList.stream().flatMap(wardrobe -> wardrobe.get().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

to get a list of all the Clothes (classes) you have set in the wardrobes

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the implementation of your Wardrobe class. If the wardrobe.add method just adds the clothes to a List in wardrobe i would suggest for java 8:

```
List<Clothes> clothesList = Arrays.asList(wardrobe.getClothes(), wardrobe1.getClothes(), wardrobe2.getClothes())
    .stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or for java 11 and higher

```
List<Clothes> clothesList = List.of(wardrobe.getClothes(),wardrobe1.getClothes(),wardrobe2.getClothes())
    .stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```